# How to pass image path as parameter for an image to be taken from camera

Tags: java, android, image, file, camera

I am passing Image as parameter in this function:

twitt.shareToTwitter(string_msg, casted_image);
**(void chintan.khetiya.android.Twitter_code.Twitt_Sharing.shareToTwitter(String msg, File Image_url))**

Now here I am selecting image from gallery, but now I want to take pic from cam and pass it. How to do it.?

Here is the full code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

// Replace your KEY here and Run ,
public final String consumer_key = "trWwomp0b09ER2A8H1cQg";
public final String secret_key = "PAC3E3CtcPcTuPl9VpCuzY6eDD8hPZPwp6gRDCviLs";
File casted_image;

String string_img_url = null, string_msg = null;
Button btn, pick, cam;
EditText et;
ImageView iv;
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        pick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        pick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent i = new Intent(
                        Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);

                startActivityForResult(i, 1);
            }
        });

        cam = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        cam.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent takePicture = new Intent(
                        MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePicture, 0);
            }
        });

        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                onClickTwitt();
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                showToast("View problem");
            }
        });

    }
}

public void Call_My_Blog(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, My_Blog.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}

// Here you can pass the string message & image path which you want to share
// in Twitter.
public void onClickTwitt() {
    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        Twitt_Sharing twitt = new Twitt_Sharing(MainActivity.this,
                consumer_key, secret_key);

        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        string_msg = et.getText().toString();

        twitt.shareToTwitter(string_msg, casted_image);

    } else {
        showToast("No Network Connection Available !!!");
    }
}

// when user will click on twitte then first that will check that is
// internet exist or not
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++) {
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void showToast(String msg) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            // file path of captured image
            String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            // file path of captured image
            casted_image = new File(filePath);

        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != imageReturnedIntent) {
            Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            casted_image = new File(picturePath);
            cursor.close();
            iv.setImageURI(selectedImage);
            // String picturePath contains the path of selected Image
            break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Log.txt:**

```
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {chintan.khetiya.android.Twitter_sharing/chintan.khetiya.android.Twitter_sharing.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2532)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:2574)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:117)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:961)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireProvider(ContentResolver.java:743)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:256)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at chintan.khetiya.android.Twitter_sharing.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:155)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3908)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2528)
09-10 16:42:26.672: E/AndroidRuntime(1888):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

to ask for a specific file location to the camera you have to do like this:

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
     cameraCaptureLocation = new File("... location goes here ...");
     intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(cameraCaptureLocation));
     startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

> But there is a problem, since I am using both cam and gallery at the same place, the function onActivityResult is already there. What to do now.?

then you have to use the `requestCode` to filter where that activity result come from. You pass one integer for `REQUEST_CAMERA` and another for `REQUEST_GALLERY`